# Get Date/Time Window from Android Room Database that is saved as String

Tags: sql, date, time, android-room

I created an app that takes Orders for a company. The Orders have a `DateReceived` field stored in a Room Database as String with format `SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy-HH:mm")`. This field would tell system when the order was received from customer.

Now I need to get all the orders for a specific `date/time` window.. for example, get all Orders where `DateReceived` was from 12/04/2020-17:00 to 13/04/2020-17:00. Any idea on how I can do this?

Comment: The easiest way would be if you save the date/time (perhaps additionally?) as a timestamp. There are different libraries to convert vice-versa. With a timestamp, you have a big number which you can compare in your SQL query.

Comment: thanks. Since I go this reply late, I manually did it by individually getting the dates and converting them into time using Java